# How to change the oembed "type"?

Tags: php, oembed

By default the oEmbed type of my wordpress posts is "rich", but I want to convert it to "Video".

I spent 2+ hours trying to find the answer but with no luck, is it possible?

Comment: What post format are you using for the post being embedded?

Comment: Video post format. If you mean't "Post type" options when you choose to post.